# Exporting Ghost to Wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress, parsing

I've been searching for a possibility to copy my Ghost Blog posts to Wordpress.

So far, I've managed to export all ghost data to a JSON file -- do you know any existing tool to convert it to something Wordpress can import?

If not, and I have to build something myself, would you recommend parsing the JSON to a WXR file or similar, or rather import into Wordpress' DB directly?

Thanks in advance!
K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use [Google Refine](https://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) to import the JSON, and export a CSV, then use [WP Ultimate CSV Importer Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/xml-and-csv-import-in-article-content/) to import it into your WordPress site. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I migrated a Ghost blog to Wordpress by reading in the Ghost JSON export, massaging it a little and using `wp_insert_post` to import the posts.

This code should be placed in your theme's functions.php file - you can export your Ghost posts (GhostData.json) at http://example.com/ghost/debug/.

Note: example below doesn't import all data, but most key fields.

```
/**
 *  A function used to programmatically create a post in WordPress.
 *
 *  http://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-a-post-in-wordpress/
 *
 *  @returns post ID if successful
 *           -1 if the post was never created
 *           -2 if a post with the same title exists
 */
function create_wp_post ($post_details) {
    // Initialize the page ID to -1. This indicates no action has been taken.
    $post_id = -1;

    $post = get_page_by_title($post_details['title'], 'OBJECT', 'post');

    // If the page title doesn't already exist, then insert the post
    if (is_null($post)) {
        // Set the post ID so that we know the post was created successfully
        $post_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
                'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                'post_author'       =>  $post_details['author'],
                'post_content'      =>  $post_details['content'],
                'post_date'         =>  $post_details['date'],
                'post_date_gmt'     =>  $post_details['date_gmt'],
                'post_name'         =>  $post_details['slug'],
                'post_status'       =>  $post_details['status'],
                'post_title'        =>  $post_details['title'],
                'post_type'         =>  'post',
                'tags_input'        =>  $post_details['tags_input']
            )
        );
    // Page title already exists, return error
    } else {
        $post_id = -2;
    }
}

/**
 *  A function used to filter Ghost blog posts into Wordpress format.
 */
function filter_ghost_posts () {
    $posts = json_decode(file_get_contents('GhostData.json'), true);

    if ($posts) { 
        foreach ($posts['data']['posts'] as $post) {
            $post_details = array(
                'author'        => $post['author_id'],
                'date'          => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post['published_at'] / 1000),
                'date_gmt'      => gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post['published_at'] / 1000),
                'id'            => $post['id'],
                'content'       => $post['html'],
                'status'        => $post['status'],
                'slug'          => $post['slug'],
                'title'         => $post['title']
            );

            // Status
            // Fix discrepancy in naming between Ghost and Wordpress
            if ($post_details['status'] === 'published') {
                $post_details['status'] = 'publish';
            }

            // Tags
            $post_tags_list = [];

            foreach ($posts['data']['posts_tags'] as $post_tags) {
                if ($post['id'] === $post_tags['post_id']) {
                    $post_tags_id = $post_tags['tag_id'];
                    array_push($post_tags_list, $posts['data']['tags'][$post_tags_id]['name']);
                }
            }

            if (count($post_tags_list) > 0) {
                $post_details['tags_input'] = implode(',', $post_tags_list);
            }

            $post_id = create_wp_post($post_details);

            if ($post_id == -1 || $post_id == -2) {
                // Error handling here
            }
        }
    } 
}

add_filter('after_setup_theme', 'filter_ghost_posts');
```

Comment: Possible clarifications:  When does this run or how do you initiate it?  Should it be removed once the import is complete?  Should the json file be placed in the same folder as the functions.php file?

Comment: The `after_setup_theme` hook is called on page load (am sure there's a smarter way to initiate it). It checks if the post title already exists in Wordpress (to prevent duplication), but regardless I'd recommend removing it after the import is complete. Note if your blog has duplicate post titles, you'll need to remove that check (but be careful to only load it once!). Yes, the JSON file should be in the same folder as functions.php (or update the path accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, but as of 2017 I still wasn't able to find a solution for Ghost > WP posts migration. What I did is:

1. Export JSON data, as described here - https://help.ghost.org/hc/en-us/articles/224112927-Import-Export-Data
2. Change a few JSON fields, like title, markdown... to post_title and post_content etc. (list of WP post fields is here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post), and remove a few unneeded ones, like update_at or amp. What I left with was:

   ID

   post_title

   post_name

   post_content

   post_status

   meta_title

   meta_description

   post_author

   post_date
3. Remove other JSON fields/structure, so there's only "posts": []
4. Use **JSON to CSV converter**, like this one - https://konklone.io/json/ and download CSV result file.
5. Now, when you have a CSV file, install WordPress **CSV Importer plugin** - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/ (or similar)
6. Upload CSV file to the importer, check if fields are selected correctly.
7. Enjoy the imported posts on your WP dashboard ;)

**Notice:**

1. Ghost does not enable image exporting with other data (as of 31/01/2017).
2. You may wish to change "post_status" from "publish" to "pending", so posts are not published right away, before you edit them properly ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for this in future:

You could use the [ghost-to-wp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ghost-to-wp) npm package. This will convert the JSON file you get as an export from Ghost into a WordPress-ready WXR file that can be directly imported into WordPress:

```
$ npm i -g ghost-to-wp

$ ghost-to-wp yourghostexport.json
```

As noted by @lomza there is *still* no way to nicely export images as part of the Ghost file so you will have to migrate images manually.

Disclosure: I am the author of `ghost-to-wp`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various importers and the best solution ended up just importing directly from RSS URL like `https://myghostblog.com/rss/` with [import-xml-feed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-xml-feed/) plugin.

P.S. Keep pagination in mind. Your RSS link might show only first page of posts by default, and so for importing other pages you'll have to manually add `/2/` `/3/` to the URL and importing each separately. (At least, that's what I needed to do.)